# How to update datatype for column in custom module?

Tags: magento2

I've `InstallSchema`that created one table that's worked fine, but later on somehow scope changed and now need to change one specific column's `datatype`.

I tried with `UpgradeSchema` but doesn't seems to work.
Any idea to implement this ?
I know I can change via deleting existing table but I'm working on git setup so....

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml:**

```
<module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.4" schema_version="1.0.4"/>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php**:

```
class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.4') < 0) {
            $connection = $setup->getConnection();
            $connection->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable('one_table'),
                'serial_number',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'length' => 255,
                    'nullable' => true,
                    'default' => '',
                    'comment' => 'Serial Number'
                ]
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Setup/InstallSchema.php**:.

```
->addColumn(
                'serial_number',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                255,
                ['nullable => false'],
                'Serial Number'
            )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply following code.

```
$setup->getConnection()->changeColumn(
    $setup->getTable('YOUR_TABLE_NAME'),
    'YOUR_OLD_COLUMN_NAME',
    'YOUR_NEW_COLUMN_NAME',
    [
        'type'     => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
        'length'   => 255,
        'nullable' => false,
        'comment'  => 'Serial Number'
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 1):

when ever version was changed just change in module.xml

```
UpgradeSchema.php

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.4') < 0) {
            $connection = $setup->getConnection();
            $connection->changeColumn(
                $setup->getTable('one_table'),
                'serial_number',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'length' => 255,
                    'nullable' => true,
                    'default' => '',
                    'comment' => 'Serial Number'
                ]
            );
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you need to changes the datatype and length for Column then use this..
like i modify the length 10.0 to 10.2,

```
if(version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.4.0', '<')) {

        $installer->getConnection()->modifyColumn(
            $installer->getTable( 'mconnect_csproduct' ),
           'csp_price',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_FLOAT,
                'nullable' => false,
                'unsigned'=> true,
                'primary'=> false,
                'length' => '10,2',
                'comment' => 'Csp Price'
            ]
            
        );
    }
```